# WiFi P2P network in Android Things

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, wifi-direct, android-things, wifip2p

I would like to create a P2P WiFi network using Android Things (5.1) and a couple of Raspberry Pi 3 or alternatively using Bluetooth. I followed the guide in the Android Developer section https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html, so my MainActivity looks like:

`private class MainActtivity {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    ....
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) {
            mManager = (WifiP2pManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
            ....
        }
    }`

However when I try to run the app, with WiFI enabled, the SystemServiceRegistry shows a message stating

> No service published for: wifip2p

and the WifiP2pManager is not retrieved.

How can I solve this issue? Does anybody know if it is possible to create a WiFi P2P network using WiFi Direct and Android Things?

Comment: would love to help, but: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Blundell I've just edited my question

Comment: Does that protocol work on RPi otherwise? It might be a specific hardware limitation

Comment: There is an open feature request on this. I would recommend voting and tracking it to get notified of future progress: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37132950

Comment: Thanks to all, I followed @Devunwired advice, and, waiting for the issue to be fixed, I'll take another path...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839955/android-8-settings-app-crashes-on-emulator-with-clean-aosp-build

Answer (score 1):

As of now (Android things stable release 1.0) WifiP2P is not supported on RPI3B,Hence try to use [Google NearBy 2.0 API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) as alternative I think it will satisfy your need.

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you think it is useful. Thanks!